# How to keep Object Highlight in Sculpt Mode? (2.93)

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe, select, sculpt

I'd like to keep the yellow highlight that appears in Object mode when an object is selected but while in sculpt mode. Blender 2.8 did this fine but I can't figure out where the option might be for 2.93... I'm trying to copy my own body sculpt to a new body and need to be able to see them both in wireframe, so having one bright yellow and one black would be more helpful than both black and I can't tell which one I'm sculpting.
I've added pictures of what I mean incase I don't make sense... I'd just like to have my object highlighted in sculpt mode as it is in object mode. (Thank you for any help!)
[image: Object mode highlight example that I want to see in sculpt mode] [image: Sculpt mode is just... dark.]